# Microsoft outlook Caught exception in remote runspace creation, The WinRM service cannot process the request Redirect location reported

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, microsoft-exchange

We are getting below error while creating Mailbox on Microsoft Exchange server using c# utility :
*Caught exception in remote runspace creation System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportRedirectException: The WinRM service cannot process the request because the request needs to be sent to a different machine.
Use the redirect information to send the request to a new machine. Redirect location reported : https://machine address/PowerShell-LiveID?PSVersion=5.1.17763.5458 ."*

Note : This command is run from a c# utility which uses the same powershell command like creating powershell session, giving credentials and all and working direct from the powershell.

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in, as text, the source code you are trying to make work. Without an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example), the question may attract downvotes and votes to close.

Comment: Error says "PowerShell-LiveID" See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-protection-powershell?view=exchange-ps